# Import multiple csv files into R and plot pairs of data from each csv file on the same graph

Tags: r

I want to import multiple csv files (12) that contain data on time t and pressure P. The headers for each file are the same (t,P) but the time  values are not common, so each t,P pair from each csv file is unique.

I can import the files without a problem:

```
filenames <- list.files(path = ("C:/Users/K125763/Documents/Mars"),  
                        # Follows a regular expression that matches:
                        pattern = "mars-[0-12]{2}.csv",
                        full.names = TRUE)
filenames <- filenames[1:12]
```

But the loop below plots each each data pair on a separate graph:

```
analyze.p <- function(filename) {
dat <- read.csv(file = filename, header = TRUE)

plot(dat$P~dat$t)

}

for (f in filenames) {
  print(f)
  analyze.p(f)
}
```

How can I get all the pairs of data on the same graph?

Comment: Do you want to distinguish between the different files?

Comment: Thanks. Yes I would like to distinguish between the files.

Answer (score 0):

I'll suggest a functional programming approach + `ggplot2`:

```
library(purrr) # functional programming tools
library(dplyr) # data wrangling
library(ggplot2) # plotting
filenames <- list.files(path = ("C:/Users/K125763/Documents/Mars"),  
                        # Follows a regular expression that matches:
                        pattern = "mars-[0-12]{2}.csv",
                        full.names = TRUE)
filenames <- filenames[1:12]

## Read and concatenate CSV files
data <- filenames %>%
  map_df(~mutate(read.csv(file = .x, header = TRUE), source_file = .x))

## Plot in a single chart
ggplot(data, aes(t, P)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_wrap('source_file')
```